# PHP - converting hexdec value to version string

Tags: php, hex

I'm working with an undocumented API that serves a version number as `hexdec` value. I wish to convert this to the versioning string.

#### Example

The API serves the following value: `117473280` (`hexdec('7008000')`)

This should be converted to the string: `7.00`

I've made the following function to do this:

```
function getFirmwareFromDechex($dechex) {
    if(!empty($dechex) || $dechex !== '0') {
        $dechex = dechex($dechex);
        $dechex = substr($dechex, 0, 3);
        $dechex = number_format($dechex / 100, 2);
            
        return $dechex;
    }
    
    return false;
}

echo getFirmwareFromDechex('117473280');
```

And this works. However, when it has to convert version 10.00, it converts it to 1.00.

How can I make the function compatible with higher version numbers such as 10.00?

#### Update

After looking how the third party displays these versions on their website, it does seem I need to pad the number to the left with a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the hex string should be 8 bytes long, so pad the start with 0's (`str_pad()` with `STR_PAD_LEFT`) and then take the first 4 characters...

```
function getFirmwareFromDechex($dechex) {
    if(!empty($dechex) || $dechex !== '0') {
        $dechex = str_pad(dechex($dechex), 8, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $dechex = substr($dechex, 0, 4);
        $dechex = number_format($dechex / 100, 2);

        return $dechex;
    }

    return false;
}
```